# Extract JSON-response into parameter

Tags: json, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, url-parameters

I need to extract this specific JSON-field into a parameter for my performance test in Visual Studio:

"ExamAnswerId": "757a3735-e626-412b-934c-e577c6963d51"

the problem occurs when I try to do this manually by right clicking the response and click "add extraction rule". The text is split up into 3 different rows with lots of unreadable numbers next to it like this:
"0x00000000  7B  22  45  78  61  6D  41  6E  73  77 65  72  49  64  22  3A {"ExamAnswerId":
0x00000010  22  37  35  37  61  33  37  33  35  2D  65  36  32  36  2D  34    "757a3735-e626-4

This will sound dumb, but I somehow need to extract 3 different parameters, only because I can't copy/paste it -- and this is also where I think I fail.

the ExamAnswerId is important for me to fullfill another webrequest later on, but I can't seem to pass it on properly.

all input greatly appreciated !

Comment: I removed your tag name from the title http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 8):

Did you see this response that got posted? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstest/thread/b26114a2-7a24-45eb-b5d1-01e9165045b0/

Just use the Extract Test like they suggest and you should work fine. Your Starts With could be "ExamAnswerId": " and your Ends With could be ". HTH.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the Extraction rule. Had to escape the quotes to get the condition to work. Like this:

Starts With: \"ExamAnswerId\":\"
Ends With: \"

Comment: I'm using VS 2013. I did NOT have to escape it and got mine to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do following steps :

1. Add all available `ExamAnswerId` in a CSV file .
2. Now add CSV as Data source.

Lets suppose CSV file name is `testdata` and `tableName=testData#csv` and `columnName=ExamAnswerId`.
Please note when you will add data source you will see table name.

3. Replace this:

   ```
   ["ExamAnswerId": "757a3735-e626-412b-934c-e577c6963d51"]
   ```

   by this:

   ```
   ["ExamAnswerId": "{{testdata.testdata#csv.ExamAnswerId}}"]
   ```

Comment: Please ignore this [] this around ["ExamAnswerId": "757a3735-e626-412b-934c-e577c6963d51"]  share with me your full jason request if having any issues you can contact me at fahad.oarans@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I  managed session in JSON. The following **link** worked for me:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b26114a2-7a24-45eb-b5d1-01e9165045b0/cant-fetch-json-value-and-extract-to-parameter?forum=vstest

Example:
0x00000000  7B  22  53  65  73  73  69  6F  6E  22  3A  22  63  66  39  37    {"Session":"cf97
0x00000010  64  33  65  61  2D  36  39  38  33  2D  34  31  37  30  2D  38

I created "Extrat_Text" with variable MySessionID
Left Boundary  "Session":
Right Boundary ",

Then I passed {{MySessionID}} in subsequent request in place of Session.

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use regex (Positive look ahead and Positive look behind)
For example I want to get access_token property in a JSON result looks like this

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3600","ext_expires_in":"0","expires_on":"1474420129","not_before":"1474416229","resource":"5fe3f443","access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci"}
```

I can use this regex:

```
(?<=\"access_token\"\:\").*(?=\")
```